# Jetpack compose Two pane layout for landscape orientation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How can I achieve two pane layout for Tablet Landscape orientation using Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Thomas Künneth has a series of posts on stuff like this: https://dev.to/tkuenneth/series/11800

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jetmagic. It was designed to create responsive apps using composable's in a way that is similar to how xml layouts are used under the older view system. Jetmagic handles all the device configuration changes that the older view system used such as orientation changes, screen size, screen density, language, etc. The demo app demonstrates orientation changes and shows two panes side-by-side where the left pane is a list and the right pane is the details. It's open source:

https://github.com/JohannBlake/Jetmagic